# vscode search hex/binary or whatever it's called

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode on linux, probably on windows too.

Steps to recreate problem:

1. Open an empty folder.
2. Create a file(txt), open file.
3. Reopen file with iso-8859-1 encoding.
4. Enter the letter `å`.
5. Save and close the file.
6. hit ctrl+shift+f and now try to search and find the letter.

I'm unable make a matching search.
I wonder if someone knows how to do this in vscode.

I've tried to enable regex search and search for `\xe5`, which is the hex value of that char in iso-8859-1. But when I do that search, vscode seems to transform that input to it's utf8 representation and search for that.

Eg. if i create a file i utf-8 and try to search for `\xe5` I do find it in that file, but I would consider that wrong since it's hex representation is `\xc3\xa5`.

Answer (score 0):

At writing time, apparently the solution would be to edit the workspace's: settings.json.
If I add `"files.encoding": "iso88591"`, it works when I search for the hex value for both utf8 and iso88591 but not the other way around.